# Добавление LatLng в Массив

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Подскажите в чем о

```
    while (temp.length) {

    var item = temp[0].split(' ');
    temp.splice(0, 2);
    var partFirst = parseFloat(item[0]);
    var partsecond = parseFloat(item[1]);

    var lat1 = Number(item[0]);
    var lng1 = Number(item[1]);

    //console.log(typeof lat + lat);
    //var point = "new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+","+lng+")";
    arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1));

    //console.log(partFirst);
    //console.log(partsecond);

    //arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(partFirst,  partsecond));

}
```

Пытаюсь добавить точки в массив пытался разными способами, но в итоге получается следующее.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете нечто весьма странное. В temp хранятся координаты? В каком виде?

Comment: var coords = coordString.split(",");  
    var temp = coords.slice(1,-1);
    var arr = [];

В CoordString храниться строка вида (lat lng,lat1 lng1,....)
Slice удаляет скобки а дальше уже по коду

Comment: Просто точку из LAt и LNG получается создать и прорисовать маркер, а вот добавлять много точек в массив не получается

Comment: new google.maps.LatLng возвращает объект класса LatLng, у которого нет свойств Lat или Lng, но есть методы lat() и lng(), которые возвращают значения координат. Если Вы хотите видеть в массиве arr координаты в виде текста, добавляйте туда new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lng1).toString(), только получится замкнутый круг... Т.е. стоит попробовать что-то сделать с данными из массива arr, а потом уже паниковать